# select one of the duplicate rows and keep the others to be NULL SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

please I have the below table with a changed row for some columns, and some of the other columns are duplicated, so I need to get the changed row and keep only one record from the duplicated rows and let the others to be NULL

```
LOG_DATE  |ITEM_ID |PROBLEM |CALL_DATE  |UCID     |ID       |ACCOUNT_NO|CALL_STATUS|
----------|--------|--------|-----------|---------|---------|----------|-----------|
2020-10-23|76409075|TYPE 1  |2020-10-23 |603405210|133283340|3825551   |Answered   |
2020-10-07|76044107|TYPE 2  |2020-10-23 |603405210|133283340|3825551   |Answered   |
2020-10-18|76297468|TYPE 3  |2020-10-23 |603405210|133283340|3825551   |Answered   |
```

the expected result

```
LOG_DATE  |ITEM_ID |PROBLEM |CALL_DATE  |UCID     |ID       |ACCOUNT_NO|CALL_STATUS|
----------|--------|--------|-----------|---------|---------|----------|-----------|
2020-10-23|76409075|TYPE 1  |2020-10-23 |603405210|133283340|3825551   |Answered   |
2020-10-07|76044107|TYPE 2  |NULL       |NULL     |NULL     |NULL      |NULL       |
2020-10-18|76297468|TYPE 3  |NULL       |NULL     |NULL     |NULL      |NULL       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I really recommend this, but you can do:

```
select LOG_DATE, ITEM_ID, PROBLEM,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by CALL_DATE, UCID, ID, ACCOUNT_NO, CALL_STATUS order by log_date desc) = 1
             then call_date
        end) as call_date,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by CALL_DATE, UCID, ID, ACCOUNT_NO, CALL_STATUS order by log_date desc) = 1
             then ucid
        end) as ucid,
       . . .
from t;
```